# Упала БД oracle: попытка соединения не удалась

Tags: oracle, sql

Всем доброго дня.

Пол года назад встала задача создать систему логистики, статистики и отчетности(включая фотоотчетность). После долгих размышлений решили посмотреть в сторону `oracle + apex`. Для разработки использовали `Oracle 11g Express Edition`, `apex 4.2.3`.

Всё шло замечательно, да и простота разработки с использование апекса не могла не радовать. Вот система была создана и потихоньку началось внедрение, примерно за месяц число пользователей возросло с нескольких десятков, до нескольких сотен.

И вроде бы всё было прекрасно, но в один прекрасный день у всех пользователей дружно в окне браузера высветилось "Попытка соединения не удалась". Ни каких видимых причин для этого не было, работы в этот день никакие не производил, отключения электричества или чего подобного не было. Никакие мои действия к нужному эффекту не привели.

**И так детали:**
ОC: Windows XP sp3
Oracle 11g XE, apex 4.2.3

**Файл: listener.ora**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = supervisor)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

**Файл sqlnet.ora**

```
# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native

# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

**Файл tnsnames.ora**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = supervisor)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

**lsnrctl status**

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>lsnrctl

LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 30-L¦T-2014 17:07
:06

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Welcome to LSNRCTL, type "help" for information.

LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                30-L¦T-2014 16:50:06
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 17 min. 5 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\supervisor\listene
r\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=supervisor)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
LSNRCTL> ^A
```

**Один из последних кусков из alert_xe**

```
Fatal NI connect error 12638, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
  Time: 29-ИЮЛ-2014 10:23:00
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12638

TNS-12638: Credential retrieval failed
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
Wed Jul 30 14:23:06 2014
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =18
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production.
Using parameter settings in server-side pfile C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\SERVER\DATABASE\INITXE.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  sessions                 = 172
  spfile                   = "C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\SERVER\DBS\SPFILEXE.ORA"
  memory_target            = 760M
  control_files            = "C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ORADATA\XE\CONTROL.DBF"
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\fast_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 10G
  undo_management          = "AUTO"
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=XEXDB)"
  shared_servers           = 4
  job_queue_processes      = 4
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\ADMIN\XE\ADUMP"
  db_name                  = "XE"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE"
Wed Jul 30 14:23:38 2014
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=2484 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:38 2014
PSP0 started with pid=3, OS id=2488 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:39 2014
VKTM started with pid=4, OS id=2496 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
Wed Jul 30 14:23:39 2014
GEN0 started with pid=5, OS id=2500 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:39 2014
DIAG started with pid=6, OS id=2504 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:39 2014
DBRM started with pid=7, OS id=2508 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:39 2014
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=2512 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:40 2014
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=2516 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:40 2014
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=2520 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:40 2014
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=2524 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:40 2014
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=2528 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:40 2014
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=2532 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:40 2014
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=2536 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:40 2014
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=2540 
Wed Jul 30 14:23:40 2014
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
Wed Jul 30 14:23:40 2014
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=2544 
starting up 4 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle
Wed Jul 30 14:23:41 2014
alter database mount exclusive
Successful mount of redo thread 1, with mount id 2735401133
Database mounted in Exclusive Mode
Lost write protection disabled
Completed: alter database mount exclusive
alter database open
Beginning crash recovery of 1 threads
Started redo scan
Aborting crash recovery due to error 333
Errors in file C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\xe\xe\trace\xe_ora_2576.trc:
ORA-00333: redo log read error block 66681 count 7098
Errors in file C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\xe\xe\trace\xe_ora_2576.trc:
ORA-00333: redo log read error block 66681 count 7098
ORA-333 signalled during: alter database open...
Wed Jul 30 14:30:52 2014
```

Характерные наблюдения: если к примеру пытаюсь подключиться к БД локально.
Набираю

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect sys as sysdba
```

Ввожу пароль, всё вроде бы нормально. Но если дальше начинаю писать какой нибудь запрос, например, номер порта: `SELECT DBMS_XDB.GETHTTPPORT FROM DUAL;`, то вылазят ошибки: `ORA-00904: DBMS_XDB.GETHTTPPORT: INVALID IDENTIFIER`

До этого опыта администрирования каких либо баз данных не имел. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать и как это вылечит.

Comment: Скорее всего истекло время действия паролей.

Посмотрите, например, [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095871/how-do-i-turn-off-oracle-password-expiration) (или в др. местах по запросу в гугле)

      oracle express password time expired 

А лучше купите промышленный релиз.

Comment: Есть еще версия, что размер БД переполнился. Обычно в express версиях ставится ограничение на размер БД. У SQL Server Express например, ограничение то ли в 1 гигабайт то ли в 4 гб... - не помню точно.

Comment: Это точно нет. Размер базы 100мб.

Comment: При любом запросе к базе говорит, что переменная не определена, либо
ORA-01219: database not open